# Filter works strangely together with product

Tags: python, filter, product, python-itertools

So, i have this code:

```
from itertools import product

data = []
for _ in range(1, 3):
    for elm in product('01', repeat=_):
        data += [''.join(elm)]

print(data)
```

And Output:

> ['0', '1', '00', '01', '10', '11']

And this one:

```
from itertools import product

data = []
for _ in range(1, 3):
    data += filter(lambda elm: ''.join(elm), product('01', repeat=_))

print(data)
```

With output:

> [('0',), ('1',), ('0', '0'), ('0', '1'), ('1', '0'), ('1', '1')]

**The programs do the same things, but for some reason the version with filter gets a strange result. Why is that?**

Comment: I think you don't understand what `filter()` does. It just checks whether the callback function returns a truthy value, it doesn't return the value.

Comment: I think you're confusing it with `map()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, guys. I mixed up filter and map. Worked hard, it happens. Thanks to Barmar a lot. Just replace filter to map...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).